# Magento 2. Retrieve information from env.php programmatically

Tags: magento2, configuration

I wish to read and use information stored in my `env.php`. Is there an entity that I can use to achieve this?

Any tips are highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Have a look at [`\Magento\Framework\App\DeploymentConfig`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3.2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/DeploymentConfig.php#L68):

Inject a deployment config object of `\Magento\Framework\App\DeploymentConfig` in your code

```
private DeploymentConfig $deploymentConfig;

public function __construct(DeploymentConfig $deploymentConfig) {
    $this->deploymentConfig = $deploymentConfig;
}
```

Then retrieve the value like this:

```
$this->deploymentConfig->get('db/connection/default/host'));
```

for example:

```
$this->deploymentConfig->get('your/custom/value'));
```

For default values, see [Magento's deployment configuration](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/config/config-php.html).