# Magento 2 : Get values defined in env.php into script

Tags: magento2

Is their any way we can get env variables values in custom script ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at \Magento\Framework\App\DeploymentConfig:

Inject a deployment config object of \Magento\Framework\App\DeploymentConfig in your code and then retrieve the value like this:

```
$deploymentConfig->get('db/connection/default/host');
```

For Example:

```
$deploymentConfig->get('your/custom/value');
```

Courtesy: [Magento 2. Retrieve information from env.php programmatically](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/215778/magento-2-retrieve-information-from-env-php-programmatically)